# Gnome installation on Debian 12 fails

Tags: linux, debian, apt

When i start the PC the graphical desktop ( [gnome](/questions/tagged/gnome) ) does not start.

If run `startx` the PC crash and i need to reboot it.

Looking at the [apt](/questions/tagged/apt) log i found that something have uninstalled my [gnome](/questions/tagged/gnome) package:

```
mrunreadable@wsdeb:~$ tail /var/log/apt/history.log 
Start-Date: 2023-09-23  01:37:18
Commandline: packagekit role='update-packages'
Install: policykit-1-gnome:amd64 (0.105-8, automatic)
Upgrade: bind9-host:amd64 (1:9.18.16-1~deb12u1, 1:9.18.19-1~deb12u1), google-chrome-stable:amd64 (117.0.5938.88-1, 117.0.5938.92-1), bind9-dnsutils:amd64 (1:9.18.16-1~deb12u1, 1:9.18.19-1~deb12u1), gnome-shell-common:amd64 (43.4-1, 43.6-1~deb12u2), bind9-libs:amd64 (1:9.18.16-1~deb12u1, 1:9.18.19-1~deb12u1)
Remove: gnome:amd64 (1:43+1), gnome-shell-extensions:amd64 (43.1-1), gnome-shell:amd64 (43.4-1), gdm3:amd64 (43.0-3), chrome-gnome-shell:amd64 (42.1-3), task-gnome-desktop:amd64 (3.73), gnome-session:amd64 (43.0-1), gnome-browser-connector:amd64 (42.1-3), gnome-core:amd64 (1:43+1), gnome-shell-extension-prefs:amd64 (43.4-1)
End-Date: 2023-09-23  01:37:32
mrunreadable@wsdeb:~$
```

I have powered off the pc the last night while keep the flags on `install the updates and power off`, but i'm sure that i haven't request to uninstall [gnome](/questions/tagged/gnome).

After that i have tried to install again [gnome](/questions/tagged/gnome) but it fails:

```
mrunreadable@wsdeb:~$ sudo apt update

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

Hit:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security InRelease
Hit:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease
Hit:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates InRelease
Hit:4 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
All packages are up to date.
mrunreadable@wsdeb:~$ sudo apt install gnome
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnome-shell : Depends: gir1.2-mutter-11 (>= 43.5) but 43.4-2 is to be installed
               Depends: libmutter-11-0 (>= 43.5) but 43.4-2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
mrunreadable@wsdeb:~$
```

Seems like the dependencies packages are too old.

This is quite strange since if i check it online [gir1.2-mutter-11](https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/gir1.2-mutter-11) and [libmutter-11-0](https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/libmutter-11-0) they show a version more recent then mine.

Checking the version of the system:

```
mrunreadable@wsdeb:~$ cat /etc/debian_version 
12.0
mrunreadable@wsdeb:~$
```

seem like it wasn't updated to the latest release which is [debian](/questions/tagged/debian) 12.1.

I can't see nothing strange in my `source.list` conf file for [apt](/questions/tagged/apt):

```
mrunreadable@wsdeb:~$ cat /etc/apt/source.list
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bookworm main contrib non-free-firmware
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bookworm main contrib non-free-firmware
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security/ bookworm-security main contrib non-free-firmware
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security/ bookworm-security main contrib non-free-firmware
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bookworm-updates main contrib non-free-firmware
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bookworm-updates main contrib non-free-firmware
mrunreadable@wsdeb:~$
```

I have other [debian](/questions/tagged/debian) systems whith the same `source.list` which works fine and they are all correctly updated to the 12.1 version.

How i can make my system upgrade to the 12.1 release and make [gnome](/questions/tagged/gnome) works again?